# scope of variable inside main in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, scope

Am I correct that a block inside main() doesn't have separate scope?

For example, if I do the following, I will get compile error:

```
static int i = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i = 2;

   { 
      int i = 3; 
   }
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Unrelated, why can't this question be edited?

Comment: @Secko Because I already proposed an edit

Comment: @Quincunx, somehow I'm not getting it. Keep refreshing, but without new content.

Comment: @Secko I approved the edit myself. It went through.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Yes, I see it now, kept refreshing without clearing my cache - weird that it couldn't load it at my side instantly.

Comment: @Secko Probably because you were on the page earlier while it was still getting approved. Remember that proposed edits aren't done immediately. :)

Comment: @DennisMeng Hmm, yes it would appear so. Thanks for that, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to compile this, I get this message:

```
error: variable i is already defined in method main(String[])
```

This means that the `static int i = 1;` does not cause the error. The scope of the first `i` in `main` is for the whole main, so when you try to make another one, in the code block, you get an error.

Note that if you declared the `i` in a block:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    {
        int i = 2;
    }
    {
        int i = 3;
    }
}
```

You don't get a compile error (see [here](http://ideone.com/ir9Ar0)).

The `static int` can be accessed in one of two ways: `this.i` (not recommended) or `ClassName.i` (recommended for accessing of a static variable)

Comment: OK, so Java does have block level scoping but not when it conflicts with the names at outer class level?  Supposedly to avoid programming error.  Thanks!

Comment: it has nothing to do with classes.  java has block level scoping provided another block on the stack (ie. method local variables) does not have a variable of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow obfuscation of stack (ie. local variables).  You can obfuscate an instance or class variable because there are other ways to access them (ie.  this.i for instance, or MainClass.i for static).